# Integral from 0 to 1 1/x

Tags: integration, substitution

I want to rewrite the integral
$\int_{0}^{1} 1/x dx$
Using the substitution $\chi=1/x$ can this be written as:
$\int_{1}^{\infty} 1/x dx$
Is this correct?

thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Sort of. Neither integral converges.

Comment: Yes, from the *assumption* the integrals exists, they are equivalent. It is easier to show the assumption is false using the new form though.

Answer (score 4):

The integrals $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ and $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ are  divergent.

However, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\int_{1}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

The equality follows from the suggested substitution $x \to 1/x$.  We can in fact, carry out the integral(s) in $(1)$ and obtain

$$\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx=-\log \epsilon$$

and

$$\int_{1}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\log (1/\epsilon)=-\log \epsilon$$

as expected!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was thinking about. However  would one geometrically not realize that they are not equal, because f(x)=1/x is symmetric around the line g(x)=x line?

Comment: They are equal analytically and geometrically.

Comment: Is it because after the substitution it changes to a Lebesgue integral? I didn't understand Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: @sri You can stick with Riemann here.

Comment: You're welcome!!  My pleasure.